# Double cover of $SO(p,2)$, where $p>2$.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, lie-groups, lie-algebras, physics

Is $Spin(p,2)$ the double cover of the connected $SO(p,2)$ ? 
Is there a reference/s where these things are given in a language accessible to a physicist ? 
Basically I am looking for a place which establishes the mapping between these two lie algebras.

Comment: The group SO(p,2) has three double covers. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: I want to understand the spin double cover. Actually I am looking for a place  where the clifford algebra construction is given for this spin group in arbitrary dimensions. I am a physics graduate student so I am interested in embedding spinors for conformal field theories in arbitrary dimensions, so it would be nice if I get a reference which is more understandable for physics students.

Comment: It's $SO_0(p,2)$. $SO(p,2)$ has 2 components. Indeed $SO_0(p,2)$ has $SO(p)\times SO(2)$ as maximal compact subgroup, so has fundamental group $\mathbf{Z}^2$ for $p=2$ and $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z})\times\mathbf{Z}$ for $p\ge 3$, and in both cases there are 3 subgroups of index 2, so 3 connected double covers.

Comment: The complexification $SO(p+2,\mathbf{C})$ has fundamental group $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ which has a single subgroup of index 2, so its the inverse image yields the subgroup corresponding to the Spin double cover. It probably means that the two other double covers of $SO_0(p,2)$ are non-linear.

Comment: The previous comments are for $p\ge 4$. For $p=3$, the fundamental group of $SO(2,1)\simeq PSL_2(\mathbf{R})$ is $\mathbf{Z}$ and there is a unique double cover, isomorphic to $SL_2(\mathbf{R})$.